# Restrict Bad Words from Input and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to validate input value and textarea text against Bad words. 
    Below code is working fine for single Badword and sentence which contains a badword.

```
badWords - contains the list of bad words
fieldValue contains input/Text area text

var badText = fieldValue.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < badWords.length; i++)
{
    if(badWords[i] != "")
    {
        if(badText.indexOf(badWords[i].trim()) > -1){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Now I am facing issue with below format. Please suggest me how to restrict the below bad word Badword: **B a d w o r d**

**EDIT**: *The question is not how to filter but how to find the cases where the word is spelled with spaces in between.*

Comment: You could remove all spaces from words and compare non-spaced words.

Comment: I'm voting to close due to this being very broad.  While the question is straight forward, the implementation, I feel, is too broad to be done in a single question.  For instance, the word "assistance' could fail a "bad word" test unless you wrote an exclusion into it.  But it is a valid word.  Hopefully this gives you an idea of why I'm saying it's too broad.

Comment: Your entire function could also be written in its current format as `textArr.some((x) => badWords.includes(x))`

Answer (score 1):

I would remove all spaces from the words and compare each using includes.

So, for each item you would use replace with the regexp `/ /g` to remove all whitespace, then convert all letters to lowercase so the search is case insensitive using `toLowerCase()` on both strings (the input string and the bad word string).

```js
function getBadWords(str) {
  let badwords = ['spider', 'monkey', 'pig']
  let words = []
  badwords.forEach(word => 
    str.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase()
      .includes(word.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase()) ? words.push(word) : null)
  return words
}

const tests = [
  'I am a spider',
  'This looks like a p i g',
  'Look at that Mon Key',
  'That spider looks like a monkey',
  'Silly words',
  'Fancy S p i d e r'
]

tests.forEach(sentence => {
  let foundWords = getBadWords(sentence)
  console.log(foundWords)
  console.log('Is bad: ' + (foundWords.length > 0))
})
```

Comment: Yes it would find `s p i d e r` and any other variation with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you split the fieldValue by spaces, you won't be easily able to search for bad words. The easiest solution would be to replace `split` with <strike>`trim`</strike> `replace(/ /g,'')` to replace all spaces, like:

```
var badText = fieldValue.replace(/ /g,'');

for (i = 0; i < badWords.length; i++)
{
    if(badWords[i] != "")
    {
        if(badText.indexOf(badWords[i]) > -1){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Akrion why? if the text includes "B a d w o r d" it will still be found, or did I miss something?

Comment: Test your code with input `bad` and then with input `b a d`

Comment: Oops, I confused the trim method. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the words you don't like in an array and then check if the value of the textarea includes any one of them.

```js
let badwords = ["badword", "flip", "hobgoblin", "turtleneck"], ele = document.querySelector.bind(document);
btn = ele("button"), ta = ele("textarea");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for(let badword of badwords) {
  if(ta.value.replace(/\s/gm, "").includes(badword)) return alert("found " + badword + "!");
  }
  alert("all clean!");
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea><button>detect!</button>
```

Comment: @PDSSandeep Changed it. 

Keep in mind this isn't a total solution because it's going to check everything after removing white space. It means that if whatever word is valid as part of another word it's also going to catch it. The solution to that is far more complex though and probably best for another question.